# android - do all Layouts require same RAM amount?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

In my `Activity` I have a complex `View` structure since I have a lot of data to display. I've got many `RelativeLayouts` with a lot of `TextViews`. I've googled around but found no clear information about complex `Layouts` and RAM usage.

So the question is: from the RAM usage point of view, does it matter if I use `RelativeLayout`, `LinearLayout` etc. or the RAM consumption is independent from `Layout` type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things (1) I don't think ram usage is the correct way to measure performance in this case. XML is pretty lightweight. I cannot image even complicated XML layouts using a lot of ram on the XML alone. Rather the components of the layout, e.g. Bitmaps, will be what uses the memory.

(2) I don't know that the type of layout matters so much as the complexity of that layout.

While I also do not have documentation to support this view I'm logicly thinking about how XML is parsed by the system. A simple `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout` should perform about the same. However, once you start nesting layout elements - as happens frequenty in `LinearLayouts` - things are probably different. As the XML needs to be parsed for the system to understand what is going on, each layer of parsing that you add is likley to decrease performance. For example, a `LinearLayout` set to vertical orientation with several sub-layouts to handle each "row" will take longer to render than one `RelativeLayout` that positions elements next to each other.

In most situations I don't think you'd notice that big of a difference. For a single activity for example rending a complex layout once will not be that difficult. But think about a list or a grid view where, even with view recycling an XML structure has to be parsed as many times as it takes to fill the screen. That's where you will start to see things slow down.

Hope that helps.

Comment: well thanks for the explanation. I'm creating an app displaying player stats for some game, I'm trying to hide as much info as possible in "slide-out menus", but the "general stats" layout MUST have like at least 30 TextViews since the data amount is pretty large. I use RelativeLayouts to group this TextViews and make the whole thing  look better, but I'm worried about memory 'cause of so many View objects

Comment: TextViews are pretty simple. I wouldn't be that concerned unless you're using really intense high resolution background images. Everything's going to get garbage collected once that stat board is destroyed anyway (unless you're leaking memory). In any event you won't know until you try. Build it and watch the heap size.

Comment: well I really don't like this message 07-26 21:13:55.528: I/dalvikvm-heap(3884): Grow heap (frag case) to 19.637MB for 8294416-byte allocation
Though I don't have many nested layouts

Comment: Yea no one likes that message. I just don't know that there is a way around that if you really need to use that kind of layout. Like a list of nested layouts will not be better. What are you putting in them? Also watch your gc messages. What % of that heap is free?